# Удалить пробелы и переходы на новую строчку

Tags: c, алгоритм

Удаляю пробелы , табуляции , переходы на новую строчку в текстовом файле(сам текстовый файл - программа )

```
char sep [10]="\n";



    char *istr;


       istr = strtok (A+107,sep);


       while (istr != NULL)
       {

          printf ("%s",istr);

          istr = strtok (NULL,sep);
       }
```

От начала строки отступаю 107 символов , чтобы не трогать объявленные библиотеки 
Но в итоге пробелы таким же способом уже не удалить,
Получается нечто такое :

```
void vpqumlntyof(char *A ,char *O4gh){          int i   = 0;    int R0x1 = strlen(A);   int Pd0x = strlen(O4gh);
if (R0x1 == Pd0x)       {               while (i   < strlen(A))         {                       if (A[i] == O4gh[i])
                {                               i++;                    }                       else break;
}               if (i   == strlen(A))           {                       puts("Correct");                }
else { puts("InCorrect"); }     }       else puts("InCorrect");}int main(){             FILE *fp;               fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\Elvin\\Documents\\Password_OIB_ETALON.txt" , "r");               char A[N];              char O4gh[80];
        int i = 0;              int j = 0;              int dlina=0;            int JBLhU9=0;           fscanf(fp, "%s", &A) != EOF;            puts(A);                puts("\nEnter the O4ghword\n");         gets(O4gh);             dlina=strlen(A);                JBLhU9=strlen(O4gh);for(i=0;i<dlina;i++)        {       A[i]=A[i]^5;    }puts(A);for(i=0;i<JBLhU9;i++){ O4gh[i]=O4gh[i]^5;}puts(O4gh);          vpqumlntyof(A,O4gh);    _getch();       return 8;}
```

Хотелось бы убрать пробелы , но они не двигаются почему-то
А есть ли возможность вставить сюда мусорный код, как при обфусцировании ?

Comment: Is space поможет ?

Comment: А если строку с разделителями сделать такой: `char sep [10]=" \t\n";`?

Comment: вау, и вправду , вы правы, спасибо

Comment: @Vladimir вынесите, пожалуйста, свой комментарий в ответ, чтобы Elvin мог бы принять его как ответ на вопрос.

Comment: Только учтите, что, по-хорошему, в строковых литералах в программе вообще ничего трогать нельзя, а также нельзя убирать некоторые пробелы, например, где-нибудь в `const volatile i`. Или конец строки после комментария или `#include`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделайте строку с разделителями такой: `char sep [10]=" \t\n";`

Comment: Не совсем понятно, зачем указан явный размер `10`.

Comment: @AnT, для меня это тоже загадка. Да, можно было явно не указывать размер массива. Но я не знаю, как автор вопроса собирается дальше использовать этот массив, - может там предполагалось сохранять и другие строки? Я же не знаю точную постановку задачи (хотя, раз там было еще про обфусцирование, то можно попытаться включить режим гадалки, да). И в таких условиях на конкретный вопрос стараюсь отвечать с минимумом изменений авторского кода. Вы считаете, что я не прав?